# How should I test this code with Junit or Mockito to simulate the non-existence of the properties file?

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to do a test to simulate the non-existence of the properties file of my class, but I can't simulate the catch part, any ideas?:

```
public CRentaProperties() throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream("/home/m1/conf/config.properties");  
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("ARCHIVO DE PROPIEDADES NO ENCONTRADO EN SERVIDOR", e);
            try {
                input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                log.error("ARCHIVO DE PROPIEDADES NO ENCONTRADO EN PROYECTO", e1);
            }
        }
        try {
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("[ERROR DE PROPERTIES]", e);
        }finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Error al cerrar el archivo", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

I manage to access the file and its properties using the following test:

```
class CRentaPropertiesTest {

    @Test
    void testUtilPropertiesTest() {
        CRentaProperties properties = null;
        try {
            properties = new CRentaProperties();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            CRentaProperties.getCRentaUtilsProperties();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        assertEquals("Queue" , properties.getqQueue());
        assertEquals("MANAGER" , properties.getqManager());
        assertEquals("14" , properties.getqPort());
        assertEquals("CHANNEL" , properties.getqChannel());
        assertNotNull( properties.getqManager());
       
    }
```

Comment: There are a few things I don't understand about your code: 1. You have a constructor `CRentaProperties()` which loads your properties file, but does nothing with them. 2. Your test calls `CRentaProperties.getCRentaUtilsProperties()`, but you haven't shown this code. How does this call relate to your question?

Comment: CRentaProperties.getCRentaUtilsProperties() works very good, but I am not able to cover this part of my code: } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("ARCHIVO DE PROPIEDADES NO ENCONTRADO EN SERVIDOR", e);
            try {
                input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                log.error("ARCHIVO DE PROPIEDADES NO ENCONTRADO EN PROYECTO", e1);
            }, I have no idea how to do it, I am trying with Mockito but it doesn´t work..

Comment: You understand that `CRentaProperties()` doesn't actually ever throw an `IOException`? So the behaviour you want to test for is the calls to `log.error(...)`?

Comment: Exactly, I have to test that, the log.error when the file doesn´t exist on server or local...

Comment: The simplest way is to create a protected constructor which takes the Logger, the Properties object, and two Strings. Use this constructor in your tests and pass mocks for the Logger and the Properties instances, and valid or invalid paths for the strings. Your public constructor will just call the protected constructor with appropriate defaults.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, a 'cheat' and the 'right' way.

The cheat is to have a protected constructor which takes the values to initialise the fields of your class. This will be accessible from your test, as by convention your test class should be in the same package as the class you are testing.

So your class becomes:

```
package org.example;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class CRentaProperties {
    public CRentaProperties() {
        this(
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(CRentaProperties.class),
                new Properties(),
                "/home/m1/conf/config.properties",
                "config.properties"
        );
    }

    protected CRentaProperties(Logger log, Properties prop, String serverPath, String projectPath) {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(serverPath);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("ARCHIVO DE PROPIEDADES NO ENCONTRADO EN SERVIDOR", e);
            try {
                input = new FileInputStream(projectPath);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                log.error("ARCHIVO DE PROPIEDADES NO ENCONTRADO EN PROYECTO", e1);
            }
        }
        try {
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("[ERROR DE PROPERTIES]", e);
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Error al cerrar el archivo", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the test is:

```
package org.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Properties;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verifyNoInteractions;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CRentaPropertiesTest {
    @Mock
    Logger logger;
    @Mock
    Properties properties;

    @Test
    public void testMissingPropertiesFile() {
        CRentaProperties cRentaProperties = new CRentaProperties(
                logger, properties, "/no/such/path", "/another/no/such/path"
        );
        verify(logger).error(eq("ARCHIVO DE PROPIEDADES NO ENCONTRADO EN SERVIDOR"), any(FileNotFoundException.class));
        verify(logger).error(eq("ARCHIVO DE PROPIEDADES NO ENCONTRADO EN PROYECTO"), any(FileNotFoundException.class));
        verifyNoInteractions(properties);
    }
}
```

The 'right' way would be to have components injected into `CRentaProperties` which were factories for a `Logger`, a `Properties` instance and the `String`s which give the file locations, but if you aren't using a dependency injection framework I think the solution above is fine.